How can I resolve dimension mismatch or weight display issues in a Kohonen neural network using Python?
I am implementing a Kohonen Self-Organizing Map (SOM) in Python. My goal is to train the SOM on scaled input data (X_scaled) and iteratively update the weights over several epochs. However, I am facing two main issues:

Dimension mismatch: I'm unsure if the dimensions of the input data X_scaled (5000 samples, 17 features) align correctly with the weight matrix weights (2x17).
Weight display inside the loop: I am unsure if displaying the weights inside the training loop is the most efficient way to track their progress.

I initialized the weight matrix with random values, and the training loop updates the weights based on the winner. I expected the SOM to train correctly, with the weights being updated over each epoch. However, I am not sure if the weight matrix is aligned correctly with the input data, and I am uncertain whether displaying the weights during each epoch is the most efficient approach.
Here is the code I am working with:
import numpy as np

class Kohonen:
    def __init__(self, weights):
        self.weights = weights

    def win(self, sample):
        distances = np.sum((sample - self.weights)**2, axis=1)
        return np.argmin(distances)

    def update(self, sample, k, alpha):
        self.weights[k] += alpha * (sample - self.weights[k])

# Initialize weights for the neural network
weights = np.random.normal(size=(2, 17), loc=0, scale=1)

# Create the Kohonen model
kohonen = Kohonen(weights)

# Number of epochs and learning rate
epochs = 260
alpha = 0.1

# Input data (ensure dimensions are consistent)
X_scaled = np.random.random((5000, 17))  # Replace with actual data

# Training loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch}")
    for sample in X_scaled:
        winner = kohonen.win(sample)
        kohonen.update(sample, winner, alpha)
    print(kohonen.weights)  # Display weights after each epoch`


what is the objective here by mentioning "...mismatch"? Do you get errors because your scripts work? Do you know what is the architecture of SOM you want to build ? why do we need to monitor weight? Your weight matrix is initialized with shape (2, 17), which means you have 2 neurons, each with weights corresponding to the 17 features of the input data. This is fine if you indeed want a 2-neuron SOM.

There is almost no change in weight if you keep a 2-neuron SOM even an n-neuron SOM even I added alpha_decay = 0.99  as the Decay factor for the learning rate to hyperparameters. I plotted weights in epochs=50, 100, ..., 260 and they are fixed. I'm afraid there is not really learning happening here. did you try to monitor the performance of calculating quantization_errors_over_epochs?

Try implementing from valid resources and use some packages for this sklearn-som 1.1.0 or MiniSom or SOMPY, nevertheless it could be done using just NumPy see this. I'm unsure class Kohonen  as Kohnen model is different SOM or what is the advantage or use case?

To resolve the issue with dimension mismatch between your input data X_scaled (5000 samples, 17 features) and the weight matrix weights (2x17), one thing you might want to check is whether the dimensions of your weight matrix align with the structure of your data.
In a Self-Organizing Map (SOM), each weight vector represents a "neuron" in the map, and the dimensions of these vectors should match the number of features in your input data. It seems like your weights matrix should have the shape (n_neurons, n_features). In your case, n_features = 17, so ensure that your weight matrix is initialized with the correct dimensions based on the number of neurons you want. For instance, if you have 2 neurons, the weight matrix should be of shape (2, 17) as it currently is.
Regarding the display of weights inside the loop, printing the weights after every epoch may not be the most efficient way to track their progress, especially for large datasets. Instead, you could print the weights every 10 epochs, or perhaps store the weights at specific epochs for analysis later.
Here's an improved version of your code:
import numpy as np

class Kohonen:
    def __init__(self, weights):
        self.weights = weights

    def win(self, sample):
        distances = np.sum((sample - self.weights)**2, axis=1)
        return np.argmin(distances)

    def update(self, sample, k, alpha):
        self.weights[k] += alpha * (sample - self.weights[k])

# Initialize weights for the neural network
weights = np.random.normal(size=(2, 17), loc=0, scale=1)

# Create the Kohonen model
kohonen = Kohonen(weights)

# Number of epochs and learning rate
epochs = 260
alpha = 0.1

# Input data (ensure dimensions are consistent)
X_scaled = np.random.random((5000, 17))  # Replace with actual data

# Training loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    if epoch % 10 == 0:  # Print weights every 10 epochs
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Weights: {kohonen.weights}")
    for sample in X_scaled:
        winner = kohonen.win(sample)
        kohonen.update(sample, winner, alpha)

